# How can I use SystemVerilog sequence properties in asserts?

Tags: system-verilog, system-verilog-assertions

I want to say "if there are an unlimited number of inputs, eventually I get an output", how can I do this?

In other parts of the script I want to assume a limited supply of inputs so I can't just write "assume there are an unlimited number of inputs" and have that hold globally.

So far I've written properties:

```
property always_another_valid_input;
   @(posedge clock) ##[1:$] valid_input;
endproperty

property foo;
    @(posedge clock) always_another_valid_input |-> ##[0:$] bar == 1;
endproperty

assert property (foo);
```

but when I run this I get an error: `property instance always_another_valid_input is not allowed in sequence expression`.

If I replace either side of the `|->` with a non-sequence property then I still get an error. It only works when both sides are non-sequence properties.

Is there a good way to work around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to [IEEE Std 1800-2012](https://standards.ieee.org/findstds/standard/1800-2012.html) § 16.12 *Declaring properties*, and more specifically § 16.12.6 *Implication*, you will see the `|->` syntax ussage is described as:

> property_expr ::=
>       ...
>       sequence_expr **`|->`** property_expr
>       sequence_expr **`|=>`** property_expr

The left hand side must be a sequence or sequence expression. It cannot be a property even if that property only contains a sequence expression.

If you declare `always_another_valid_input` as a `sequence` instead of a `property`, your code will compile

```
sequence always_another_valid_input;
   @(posedge clock) ##[1:$] valid_input;
endsequence
```